# a divides b is a POSET on set of Natural numbers(N) but not Integers(Z)

Tags: relations

`a divides b` is not a partial ordering on the set Z of integers since a | b and b | a need not imply a = b.

This is a line from Schaum's outline of discrete mathematics ( chapter 2 Relations pg. 33)

I understood that it is a POSET for set of Natural numbers $N$. But, it even holds the necessary conditions to be a POSET on set of integers $Z$.

My approach:

1. It is reflexive as $a|a\ \forall a \in Z $.
2. It is anti-symmetric as $a|b \ , b|a \implies a=b \forall a,b \in Z$.
3. It is transitive too.

Then why is it mentioned that it is not a POSET on $Z$ ?

Comment: Two of the conditions remain true. One fails. Here's a slightly obscure hint: $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Thanks for the quick response. This is really helpful because $1|-1$ and $-1|1$ but `1 != -1`. Hence not antisymmetric and so not a poset on Z. Thank you!

Comment: In general, $-n\mid n$ and vice versa

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes sir indeed. If it was asked to check if `Is a divides b a POSET on set of non negative integers` $Z+$, it would've been false, right? As it is not reflexive when a is 0.

Comment: @taurus05 That's actually a poset, there's no such problem with $0$, it will be simply the *greatest* element: we have $n|0$ for every nonnegative integer $n$, while $0|n\implies n=0$.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: Apart from this, i also found that $0 \in Z$ and $0|0\ is\ undefined$. Hence, it is not reflexive too. Is this right?